# how to lock the remote pc while taking it in remote control using temviewer

Tags: windows-7, teamviewer

I am currently using a system by remote control.
But what ever i do, its is displayed in the actual physical computer.

I want to completely hide my operations.

More like in windows remote desktop connection.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? What is your evil masterplan? Is it even legal/ethical to do this?

Comment: I guess you just want to use rdp? You can use Teamviewer VPN to tunnel RDP, if this helps.

Comment: You can connect to another computer as Teamviewer and from it,connect as RDP to the requested computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [logmein](https://secure.logmein.com/). there is as option as [blank screen](https://secure.logmein.com/welcome/webhelp/Pro/LogMeIn/t_remotecontrol_blank.html) in options. The same options are also available in Teamviewer. goto teamviewer control panel, from **Actions** tab select **show blank screen**